# how to copy any folder structure without subfolders

Tags: file, powershell, copy, filesystems, robocopy

does anyone have an idea, how to copy the folder structure without any subfolders and files?
i Tried with robocopy but did not find any command to exclude the subfolder.

Thank you.

Comment: Robocopy has XF and XD swithces for excluding. Provide a sample structure and explain which parts you want to include & exclude.

Comment: how can i realise this? i have more than thousands of folders and millions of subfolders. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most elegant or efficient solution but it should work($destinationRoot and $sourceRoot are case sEnSitivE):

```
$destinationRoot = "D:\temp";  
$sourceRoot = "U:\Scripts";  
$dirs = ls -Attributes d -Recurse;  
foreach($dir in $dirs){  
    $np = ($destinationRoot + $dir.FullName.replace($sourceRoot,""));   
    md $np -Force -ea 0;  
}
```

Comment: this does the trick. how can i copy trough unc path with other credentials?

Comment: This is different and a surprisingly complicated question when it comes to Powershell. It will be better if you search SO for an answer as there are quite a few.

Comment: thank you for the solution i think this might help some people. my solutions is to export folders into a text file and later create the folders in the right location with text import and foreach -> folder create.